# text file is erased when i open ('r' method) a file and try to readline it

Tags: python, readline

Here is my code-
Python 3.3 on windows 10
'File' is a txt file.
When i run this code, the file data is erased.  I dont understand why- shouldn't happen when using mode 'r'.  The read line is also blank.

```
with open(file, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        line = readline(f)
        print(' data= ', line)
        mydat = inst23.readData2Dict(line)
        print(mydat)
        if (mydat['Date'] == '15.04.2016' and mydat['Dat1'] <  '25.50'):
            print('Both = ', mydat['Both'])
```

Comment: Are you sure the file wasn't blank when you started?

Comment: Do you mean that when you open the file externally, all data is gone? That's highly improbable! Or is it just the readline ouptut your are asking about?

Comment: wnnmaw and trans1st0r - I check the txt file just before running and it has my data.  I run the code above, then I open the txt file again and the txt file is blank.  I am not getting any "errors" when I run the code.  Any ideas what is going on here?

Comment: I double checked the file and it was not blank initially.

Comment: I figured out that the text file was written in Cp1252.  I don't know if this would cause the problem or not.

Comment: I deleted the readline(f) line and it works fine.  Problem solved.  Thanks for your help